# Как лучше всего подготовиться к ЕГЭ по математике?

Tags: математика

Дело в том, что через 1.5 месяца приходит наказание в виде экзамена, но к сожалению есть некоторые пропуски в знаниях в области алгебры и геометрии (буквально 6 заданий, остальные решаю спокойно), так вот, как лучше подтянуть геометрию, стереометрию и усложненные уравнения (sin, cos, tg, ctg, log и тому подобное)?

Comment: Сайт посвящён программированию, а не вопросам подготовки к экзаменам по математике.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что не соответствует тематике StackOverflow on russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно это весьма грязный хак, но если времени уже осталось мало, то проще готовится, изучая и самому решая как можно большее количество прошлогодних вариантов, чем заного изучать всю школьную программу. И еще наверное стоит сходить на несколько ВУЗовских олимпиад. В некоторых ВУЗах участие в них дает больше шансов на поступление.

Это эвристический подход сработает, потому что задачи для школьников как правильно однотипные(очень много работы для проверяющего и желающих поступить), составляются одними и теми же людьми и редко меняются из года в год.

И да, все же Ваш вопрос таки не слишком в тему для этого сайта. Здесь обсуждают в основном практические проблемы, связанные с разработкой ПО.